# How to select an attribute of a list elements in jpql

Tags: java, sql, maven, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have a Project entity, containing a list of its creators,

`public class Project implements Serializable {
    @ManyToMany
    private List<Creator> creator;`

I need a method with a parameter creator id, returning a list of the projects created by that creator, here is my idea

```
 public List<Project> MyOwnProjects(int idcreator){
String jpql= "select p from Project p where p.creator.get(i).getCode()= :idcreator";

Query query= em.createQuery(jpql);
query.setParameter("idcreator", idcreator);     
return (List<Project>)query.getResultList();
}
```

This query is not valid of course, How can I do that ?

Comment: What database is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can't modify the mapping, I would do it the other way around : add a @ManyToMany association in your Creator entity (using MappedBy), then something like this (my JPQL is quite rusty)

```
"select p from creator left join fetch creator.project p where creator.id = :idcreator "
```